# Eigen Map raw buffer

Tags: eigen, eigen3, placement-new

Plese see code below:

```
double* data = new double[100];
boost::shared_ptr<Eigen::VectorXd> rfstdevs = boost::make_shared<Eigen::VectorXd>(
        Eigen::Map<Eigen::RowVectorXd>(data, 1, 100));
```

My understanding is that Eigen would take the buffer directly and use it, so should I manually free the data buffer or the newly created  VectorXd would do it for me?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

This performs a deep copy from, so you need to free `data`. If you don't want a deep copy, then use the `Map` object directly:

```
Map<RowVectorXd> rfstdevs(data,1,100);
```

You will still need to delete `data` yourself, `Map` won't do it as it does not know where it comes from.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the Map functions as this, but I have given the Map to Eigen::VectorXd as a variable and constructed a new Eigen::VectorXd as above, in the boost::make_shared<VectorXd>(Map<RowVectorXd>)... wonder if this constructor actually makes a copy or it just uses the internal buffer from the Map? If uses internal buffer from the Map, I assume that the newly constructed share_ptr<VectorXd> would try to free the buffer upon deconstruction?

Comment: As I wrote, your code performs a deep copy from the Map to the VectorXd.

Comment: e... Thank you... I had hoped it was a shallow copy. Does Eigen support something like move semantics in C++11?

Comment: @Michael You can `move` (or `swap`) e.g., `VectorXd` and `MatrixXd`, but you can't move from a `Map`, because the `Map` does not own its memory. You can in fact never have Eigen types take ownership of memory created outside Eigen types.